# Terminology used in a problem: Let $S$ be the set of integers and, as usual, let $A(S)$ be the set of all one-to-one mappings of

Tags: group-theory

I was reading about group theory in a book. There was a particular terminology used in the book which I couldn't get. It was used in describing about a particular group.

> Let $S$ be the set of integers and, as usual, let $A(S)$ be the set of all one-to-one mappings of $S$ onto itself. Let $G$ be the set of all elements in $A(S)$ which move only a finite number of elements of $S$, that is,  $\sigma \in G$ if and only if the number of $x$ in $S$ such that $x\sigma \neq x$ is finite. If $\sigma,\tau \in G $, let $\,\sigma\!\cdot\!\tau\,$ be the product of $\sigma $ and $\tau$ as elements of $A(S)$. We claim that $G$ is a group relative to this operation.

Now, I am not quite getting what is meant by "Let $G$ be the set of all elements in $A(S)$ which move only a finite number of elements of $S$"? Also, what is meant by "$\sigma \in G$ if and only if the number of $x$ in $S$ such that $x\sigma \neq x$ is finite"? I am not quite getting it...

Comment: Which bit of terminology don't you get?

Comment: @Shaun the portion u deleted while editing my original post...

Comment: @Shaun U deleted my original query while editing it ...please re-edit it back...

Comment: @Shaun anyways , I rollback-ed it...thank you....

Comment: If $S= \{ \ldots, -2,-1,0,1,2,\ldots \}$ a *mapping* $\mu : S \to S$ is a function $\mu(n)=m$ that maps integers into integers and, in general, $m \ne n$. The author consider only those mappings $\sigma$ that "move" only a finite amount of numbers, i.e. such that $\sigma(n)=n$ for all $n$ except for a finite amount of numbers.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So that means the author considers all those functions $\sigma$ which are such that $\sigma(m)=m$ for all $m $ except for a finite number of cases .  Is this what the author meant by "considering all those elements in $A(S)$ which move only a finite number of elements of $S$ "? ...

Comment: Yes. And it's not all those *functions*; it's all those *bijections*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f\in A(S)$. Define:
$$\operatorname{Move}(f):=\{s\in S\mid f(s)\ne s\}$$
Therefore your $G$ matches the following definition:
$$G:=\{f\in A(S)\mid \operatorname{Move}(f)\text{ is finite}\}$$
Since $A(S)$ is a group, you are left to prove that $f,g\in G\Longrightarrow fg^{-1}\in G$ (one-step subgroup test). But this is the case, because $fg^{-1}\in A(S)$ and $\operatorname{Move}(fg^{-1})\subseteq \operatorname{Move}(f^{-1})\cup \operatorname{Move}(g^{-1})$, which already uses the fact that, for every $h\in A(S)$, $h^{-1}(s)\ne s\iff h(s)\ne s$ (whence $\operatorname{Move}(h)=\operatorname{Move}(h^{-1})$).